# Masonry for Wordpress Recent Posts not displaying correctly

Tags: wordpress, masonry

I'm trying to implement a Masonry gallery beneath the main image of a website. I'm not even sure if I'm getting close to making it successful. Currently, the thumbnails are in a line, but only four to a line instead of 5, and they are not filling up the white space with each other, as is obviously the desired result.

Here's the CSS:

```
#mason {
    width:      950px; /* width of the entire container for the wall */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.brick {
    width:      20%; /* width of each brick less the padding inbetween */
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-table;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="mason">
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=100'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="brick">
<div class="brick_featured_image">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 $size=75;
 ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Click to view: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size );  }  ?>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
</div>
```

Here's what I have added to my functions.php:

```
function mason_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-masonry' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mason_script' );
```

And here's the script I added to my footer:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '#mason' ).masonry( { columnWidth: 190 } );
} );
</script>
```

I followed the steps at this website:
http://pastebin.com/y0D0NDSf

And everything can currently be viewed here:
http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/test-3/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's the CSS...which by the way is being declared twice (you're loading your site `style.css` file twice).

This should get you on track:

```
.#wrapper {
    padding: 5px 0px 40px 5px;
}

 .brick {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your response did you mean to write ".#wrapper"? And exclude "#mason"?

Comment: I removed the second style sheet call and added your CSS changes, but the code is still producing the same results.

Comment: If I add `float: left;` to the `.brick` css then it appears like the image in your screenshot with the 7th post appearing below the bottom line of the 6th post.

Comment: My code is fixes...not removing anything. So keep your same code and replace the padding values for `#wrapper` and margins for `.brick`. Sorry - should have been more clear.

Comment: I did try that, but when I added a 7th post to double-check that it would work correctly the 7th post thumbnail showed up far below where it should. http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/test-3/